# Trouble switching a CSS menu from hover to focus

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to switch a "mega menu" over from 'hover' to 'focus'.  I wish to have the drop down menus displayed "on click" and to stay displayed until some other top level selection is clicked.  I need a pure CSS solution, if at all possible.

Based on other Q/A here I have changed the CSS elements from 'hover' to 'focus' and added tabindex="1" to the relevant 'li' tags.  It's working great in Chrome, but not in any other browsers that I have tried.

JS fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/only1chip/QzwXV/

```
    <li tabindex="1"><a href="#_" class="menuitem_drop">Home</a>
```

My apologies in advance: you will have to make your JS fiddle "results" window fairly wide before the menu will "go horizontal" - the results will be nonsensical until you do this...  I tried to make it skinny just for the fiddle, but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Chip

PS And yes, that 'mega menu' is a commercial product - we will certainly pay the full asking price if we can modify it to work for our application.

Comment: Pure CSS on click? Better use a robust JS solution (you can make it work in IE6) than a pure CSS solution for the sake of using CSS...

Comment: In the jsfiddle the dropdowns *do* work on click and not hover.  What's the problem?

Comment: @ExplosionPills "It's working great in Chrome, but not in any other browsers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the anchor tags are stealing focus when clicked in non-webkit browsers. You might try changing them to `span` tags. I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzwXV/1/) with a working example, tested in Chrome 27 and Firefox 21.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - this was exactly the information/hint/solution I needed to get productive on my project again.  I appreciate it greatly!